Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS: Upgrade issue for MySQL client
I run Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS but I am not sure this is correct.
mysqld reports

mysqld --version
/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

When I try to do an upgrade, apt says the paket system is broken with the following message:

mysql-server-8.0: Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is already installed
Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is already installed
Depends: perl:any (>= 5.6) but it is a virtual package

Looks like, mysql-client requires a newer version which I do not have.
How can I resolve this issue?

Fixed it with running sudo apt --fix-broken install first.
